# What was the glyph origin of 己? What was its original meaning?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I understand that the current meaning of 己 is "oneself", which is different to its original meaning. Now I am curious about the history of the character.

I found different opinions regarding 己's glyph origin:

- [skein of silk for binding objects](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%E5%B7%B1&oldid=71841387)
- [three horizontal lines where a skein of thread is winded](https://okjiten.jp/kanji974.html)
- [loom](https://hanziyuan.net/#%E5%B7%B1)

I also tried to look for information regarding the original meaning of 己, and [one source](https://ichigoichina.jp/kanji/3/%E5%B7%B1) said it is "to sort out". If that is the case, I still do not understand how an ideogram of a skein of silk/thread or loom was being used to express the meaning of "to sort out".

This is my first post here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not a very satisfying answer, but it looks like there is no consensus as to the original meaning of「己」at the moment.

[Outlier](https://www.outlier-linguistics.com/products/outlier-dictionary-of-chinese-characters)

> It is not clear what the original meaning and form of 己 are. It was used in early texts as one of the Heavenly Stems (天干 tiāngān).
> [Reference, p. 964]

The reference:

> 季旭昇，2004《說文新證》，台北：藝文印書館印行，2014年9月第二版。

The reference from p. 964 of《說文新證》:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

> I found different opinions regarding 己's glyph origin:...
>
> I also tried to look for information regarding the original meaning of 己,..

**己** 字源字形 -

[image]

**己** 详细解释:

(1) (象形.甲骨文字形，象绳曲之形.) “己”是古“纪”字，假借作“自己”用。①**本义:**丝的头绪，用以缠束丝。②自己) 自己，本人 [oneself]

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%B7%B1